# Why I have to add IBOutlet identifier to my delegate when inside apple sdk there isn't any IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created the following custom view:

```
@interface TNGalleryView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) id <TNGalleryViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <TNGalleryViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

I can assign delegate of it in code, but when I want to assign delegate in IB, I can't. I have to change my code to:

```
@interface TNGalleryView : UIView

@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id <TNGalleryViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id <TNGalleryViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

and then I can assign delegate and dataSource in IB.

Why if i would like to assign delegate and dataSource in IB I have to add IBOutlet identifier, but inside apple sdk there isn't any IBOutlets? For example this part of UICollectionView declaration:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) @interface UICollectionView : UIScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout; // the designated initializer

@property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionViewLayout *collectionViewLayout;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UICollectionViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UICollectionViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

There isn't any IBOutlet, nevertheless I can assign dataSource and delegate to it in IB.

Comment: I don't understand your question...anyways - delegates don't need IBOutlet in their declaration..

Comment: @TusharKoul I updated question. Now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a good question!

Open your storyboard/xib with text editor,search "TNGalleryView",you will found xml tag like this:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ke7-rk-01e" customClass="TNGalleryView">
    <rect key="frame" x="86" y="309" width="160" height="252"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
</view>
```

Note that: TNGalleryView was wrapped in a "view" tag with a property: customClass="TNGalleryView"

Now add a UICollectionView in storyboard/xib, save and reopne storyboard/xib with text editor,search "collectionView",you will found xml tag like this:

```
<collectionView opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" minimumZoomScale="0.0" maximumZoomScale="0.0" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ouM-xa-T6a">
   <rect key="frame" x="93" y="72" width="160" height="252"/>
   <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
   <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="Cv0-O7-zGY">
   <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
   <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
   <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
   <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
    </collectionViewFlowLayout>

</collectionView>
```

Now,you will find the different ,collectionView is wrapped in a "collectionView" tag

I guess that was the reason why you can't assign custom delegate in IB without set the custom delegate to be a IBOutlet.

**UPDATE**

No enought reputation to comment other poeple's answer.So i say something here: read the question clearly,and have a test in xcode,you will realize what Sergey Demchenko's question is:

First,if TNGalleryViewDelegate is declare in this way:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <TNGalleryViewDelegate> delegate;
```

The xcode screen shot:
[image]

Now if TNGalleryViewDelegate is declare in this way:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet id <TNGalleryViewDelegate> delegate;
```

The xcode screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `IBOutlet` decorator is to let Interface builder know that it can connect to the property. It is just a hint that produces no code.

Only those properties that will connect to Interface elements need IBOutlet. That is the objects that you connect by dragging between the GUI object and the code. It is a hint to Interface builder that a property in the code can be connected to.

Comment: ok, it is clear. But why @property (nonatomic, assign) id <UICollectionViewDelegate> delegate; is not contains IBOutlet?

Comment: Like the answers says...IBOutlet is just a decorator...a delegate declaration has no need for it at all. So it doesn't contain "IBOutlet"

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a pretty good question. Since Xcode and IB are opaque - meaning no one but Apple has the source, all we can do is guess. My guess is that given the relatively small number of UIView subclasses that take delegates and data sources, Apple has just hardcoded the knowledge into IB.

One reason for this would be that IB doesn't want to parse every one of those UIView subclasses every time you switch to a Storyboard or NIB view.

In any case, all we can do is speculate. Its not so difficult adding the IBOutlet keyword to your own file.

Answer (score 0):

Outlets are not necessarily exposed in the header file. You can do the same in your own classes by defining the outlets inside your .m file.

Comment: In fact it is a best practice to restrict both `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` to the implementation (.m) file unless they need to be available outside the class. This allows exposing only those items that need to be explicitly public.

Comment: @Zaph even though it is possible, isn't it against the principle of OOP. The IBoutlets are accessed by another file outside the scope of the class, so technically they SHOULD be exposed in the .h file.

Comment: Making IBOutlets and IBations private would also hinder automated testing. I feel they should be kept in the .h itself unless really necessary.

Comment: We have been moving away from exposing to much of the internal working as possible. This allows us to change the internal implementation without concern of breaking code that relies on the class. The only part we can't change is that part exposed to users of the class.

Comment: Best practice is to expose as little as possible, that is good OOD. Exposing internal portions of a class just for testing also makes the methods available and advertised to all users of the class. As for testing, in the test file create a category on the class with these methods added to expose them for the test cases. Another option is to have an additional private header file that contains the items and include the main header file in that. In the .m file included the private header as well as in the test classes. Apple does this extensively.

Comment: @Zaph is there no Apple document that specifies all these best practices? I've seen the Obj-C best practices on Stack overflow and I don't think this point is in there..